# How to type a text in input box in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I need to know how can we type a string in input box using puppeteer. I know it can be done like this:

```
await page.type('input[name=pickup]', 'test comment', {delay: 200})
```

But what if the input box does not have a name or id, and instead it has a value name or title id? Like this:

```
await page.type('[title id^="pickupAgingComment"]', 'test comment', {delay: 200})
```

OR

```
await page.type('[value name^="pickupAgingComment"]', 'test comment', {delay: 200})
```

The last two does not work actually.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

ok, I just figured out with this:

```
await page.type('input[name=pickupAgingComment]', 'test comment', {delay: 20})
```

Though the selector is a value name, I tried removing value and used just name literal.
It is working for value name also.

Comment: For future reference, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp `inb4 w3fools`